# Fastest Proxy Iteration in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-requests, iterator

Let's say I have a list that contains 10,000+ proxies

```
proxy_list = ['ip:port','ip:port',.....10,000+ items]
```

How do I iterate it to get the proxies that works for my pc? Using the following code it is possible to find it , but takes 5*10,000 seconds to get completed. How would I iterate through the list faster?

```
import requests
result=[]
for I in proxy_list:
    try:
        requests.get('http:\\www.httpbin.org\ip',proxies = {'https' : I, 'http' : I } ,timeout = 5)
        result.append(I)
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use threading, this would allow the program to check multiple proxies at once.

```py
import requests
import threading
import concurrent.futures

appendLock = threading.Lock() """This is to keep multiple threads from appending 
to the list at the same time"""

workers = 10 """This is the number of threads that will iterate through your proxy list.
In my experience, increasing this number higher than 30 causes problems."""

proxy_list = ['ip:port','ip:port',.....10,000+ items]

result = []

def proxyCheck(proxy):
    try:
        requests.get('http://www.httpbin.org/ip',proxies = {'https' : I, 'http' : I } ,timeout = 5)
        with appendLock:
            result.append(I)
    except:
        pass

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
    for proxy in proxy_list:
        executor.submit(proxyCheck(proxy))
```

Comment: So if I give worker =20, it shall reduce the time by 20? Won't the script lag?

Comment: No, the program is simply allocating itself more processing power from your CPU. Traditionally, a Python program will run with 1 thread. However in this case using concurrent.futures allows us to use more than one thread, effectively speeding up the program. I can't get too far into the details before I am way out of my league so here is an article that does a good job explaining threading in Python: https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/

Comment: So with thread I can run two loops ,one in background (daemon) and one the normal way? Thank-you. +1 for answer one of my other doubts

Comment: it is still taking one by one

Comment: tried     `appendLock = threading.Lock()
    workers = 20
    print("getting....")
    def proxyCheck(proxy,wow):
        try:
            res=requests.get('http://www.httpbin.org/ip',proxies = {'https' : proxy, 'http' : proxy } ,timeout = 4)
            print(res.json())
            with appendLock:
                proxyman.append(wow)
        except:
            pass    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
        for i in result:
            proxy = i[0]+':'+i[1]
            executor.submit(proxyCheck(proxy,i))` it prints 1 by 1 slowly