# How to get the correct file size for gzip file before downloading

Tags: python, http, python-requests, gzip, tqdm

Currently, I am trying to download a compressed dataset gzip file from a website and using the tqdm library to display the downloading progress. However, I noticed the tqdm progress bar will overflow due to the inaccurate file size from "Content-Length" in the response header. I will paste the sample code below as a reference:

```
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm

url = 'https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./enron/enron_mail_20150507.tar.gz'
filename = url.split('/')[-1]

with requests.get(url, stream=True) as req:
    with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
        print('downloading the Enron dataset')
        total_size = int(req.headers['Content-Length'])
        print(req.headers)
        progress = tqdm(total=(total_size),
            unit='iB', unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024, ascii=' █',
            bar_format='{l_bar}{bar:50}{r_bar}{bar:-50b}')
        for chunk in req.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:
                progress.update(len(chunk))
                file.write(chunk)
        print('download complete!')
```

I did some searching, but could not find a good solution to this issue. Are there any ways to pre-determine the gzip file size that need to be downloaded? Or any suggestions to work around it?

Comment: Does my answer help you?

Answer (score -1):

There is an alternate way to find the size. But this method cannot be used for you file since it may take ages (i guess). It is:

```
res = requests.get('https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./enron/enron_mail_20150507.tar.gz')
file_size = len(res.content)
```

---

Edit!
Found a solution:

```
file_size = int(requests.head('https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./enron/enron_mail_20150507.tar.gz', headers={'accept-encoding': ''}).headers['Content-Length'])
```

Comment: Don't do a `get` request to the `host` if you are not willing to do a download. same as when you post the `url` within your browser. use `head` for such cases.

Comment: Requests head method is not giving the correct file size. The get method will get the correct size, but it is after the downloading. In my case, I would like to get the total size for the progress bar.

Answer (score -1):

```py
import requests
from hurry.filesize import size

headers = {'accept-encoding': ''}


def main(url):
    r = requests.head(url, headers=headers)
    cl = int(r.headers['Content-Length'])
    print(size(cl))


main("https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./enron/enron_mail_20150507.tar.gz")
```

Output:

```
422M
```

Comment: @InfinityTM what do you mean ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61135835/setting-proxy-using-command-prompt-failure

Comment: and this especially requires your attetion lolhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/61012763/fastest-proxy-iteration-in-python

Comment: sorry ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61012763/fastest-proxy-iteration-in-python

Comment: The file size in this case is still incorrect. It should be 1.69 GB.

Comment: @domsupamoe the file size is absolutely correct in case if you check the download size !

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I am a little lost why it is correct if it does not match the actual downloaded size?

Comment: @domsupamoe check the [print screen](https://imgur.com/zGCqSf4)

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I think your downloader is also not giving you the correct size. https://imgur.com/a/xKTzmI8

Comment: In the interests of bringing this comment thread to a polite close, I downloaded and uncompressed the file.  443 MB compressed, 1.4 GB uncompressed.  APFS.  The response header was pretty accurate.

Comment: @Chris so the `OP` was unclear about his target for getting the real size without compressed .