# Combine parsing of html inside and outside of iframe w/ BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, selenium, iframe, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to scrape from a real estate listing website using Selenium/BS4/Python. The script extracts the listing page links, before parsing the html on each listing page. I am using a Chrome Extension called Property Data that manifests as an iframe on each page and displays data for the particular area that listing is in (e.g. average prices, yields etc for that zipcode/postcode.) It takes about 15 seconds to load the results on each listing page. Please see screenshot of the extension on the right-hand side of the page:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMMWz.jpg

iframe html from Chrome inspect:

```
<div class="row one-col print-hidden"><div class="cell"><div class="module"><div class="hl-1 pad-16" style="padding-top: 0 !important;"><div class="propertydata" style="height: 410px; overflow: none;"><iframe scrolling="no" style="width: 302px; height: 410px; margin: 0; border: 0;" src="https://propertydata.co.uk/extension/1.3/51.579520/-0.235261/rightmove/78617383/399950/2"></iframe></div></div></div></div></div>
```

My question is:
**Once the chrome extension iframe and results are loaded on the listing page, how do I amend the get_html_data function in the code below so it first parses the html of the existing page and then switches to parsing and locating elements in the iframe?**

```
rightmove_hmo_search = "https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=POSTCODE%5E1619792&maxBedrooms=4&minBedrooms=2&maxPrice=500000&radius=10.0&sortType=18&propertyTypes=&maxDaysSinceAdded=14&includeSSTC=false&mustHave=&dontShow=newHome%2CsharedOwnership%2Cretirement&furnishTypes=&keywords=stpp%2Cloft"

#identify and extract listing links from each page (in this case first page only)
def get_house_links(url, driver, pages=1):
    house_links = []
    driver.get(url)
    for i in range(pages):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        listings = soup.find_all("a", class_="propertyCard-moreInfoItem is-carousel")
        page_data = ['https://rightmove.co.uk' + row['href'] for row in listings]
        house_links.append(page_data)
        print(house_links)
       # next_button = soup.select('button[class="pagination-button pagination-direction pagination-direction--next"]')
       # if next_button:
         #   for page in range(0, 1):
        #        index = page * 24
        #        next_button_link = 'https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=POSTCODE%5E1619792&maxBedrooms=4&minBedrooms=2&maxPrice=500000&radius=10.0&sortType=18&' + '&index=' + str(index) + '&propertyTypes=&maxDaysSinceAdded=14&includeSSTC=false&mustHave=&dontShow=newHome%2CsharedOwnership%2Cretirement&furnishTypes=&keywords=stpp%2Cloft'
         #       driver.get(next_button_link)
         #       if page > 1:
          #          break


    return house_links


#get html data from url and return as object
def get_html_data(url, driver):
    driver.get(url)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@class, 'key')]")))
    except TimeoutException:
        print("page took too long to load")
    BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
    time.sleep(3)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

    return soup
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you even using `selenium`, FYI, the data is already located within the `page` source under `script` tag. so you even don't need to collect the `urls` and then loop to access each one of them.

All of that can be done within single call!

I've loaded it within `JSON` dict, so you can access it and parse whatever you need.

```py
import requests
import re
import json


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    match = re.search(r"window.jsonModel = ({.+})", r.text).group(1)
    data = json.loads(match)
    hview = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
    print(data.keys())
    print(hview)


main("https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=POSTCODE%5E1619792&maxBedrooms=4&minBedrooms=2&maxPrice=500000&radius=10.0&sortType=18&propertyTypes=&maxDaysSinceAdded=14&includeSSTC=false&mustHave=&dontShow=newHome%2CsharedOwnership%2Cretirement&furnishTypes=&keywords=stpp%2Cloft")
```

Output:

```
dict_keys(['properties', 'resultCount', 'searchParametersDescription', 'radiusOptions', 'priceOptions', 'bedroomOptions', 'addedToSiteOptions', 'mustHaveOptions', 'dontShowOptions', 'furnishOptions', 'letTypeOptions', 'sortOptions', 'applicationProperties', 'staticMapUrl', 'shortLocationDescription', 'timestamp', 'bot', 'deviceType', 'propertySchema', 'sidebarModel', 
'seoModel', 'mapViewUrl', 'legacyUrl', 'listViewUrl', 'pageTitle', 'metaDescription', 'recentSearchModel', 'maxCardsPerPage', 'countryCode', 'countryId', 'currencyCodeOptions', 'areaSizeUnitOptions', 'sizeOptions', 'priceTypeOptions', 'showFeaturedAgent', 'showNewDrawASearch', 'commercialChannel', 'disambiguationPagePath', 'dfpModel', 'noResultsModel', 'urlPath', 'tileGeometry', 'geohashTerms', 'comscore', 'cookiePolicies', 'formattedExchangeRateDate', 'authenticated', 'location', 'searchParameters', 'featureSwitchStateForUser', 'pagination'])
```

Your desired data is within that key `properties`:

For example, this is the first offer:

```
"properties": [
        {
            "id": 78658603,
            "bedrooms": 2,
            "numberOfImages": 10,
            "numberOfFloorplans": 1,
            "numberOfVirtualTours": 0,
            "summary": "Presented in outstanding condition, this gorgeous 2 bedroom apartment is set within a modern development and offers a bright open-plan reception room/kitchen, excellent fixtures and a charming private Balcony.",
            "displayAddress": "Haydons Road, Wimbledon, London, SW19",
            "countryCode": "GB",
            "location": {
                "latitude": 51.42015,
                "longitude": -0.187532
            },
            "propertySubType": "Flat",
            "listingUpdate": {
                "listingUpdateReason": "new",
                "listingUpdateDate": "2020-04-03T11:08:02Z"
            },
            "premiumListing": false,
            "featuredProperty": true,
            "price": {
                "amount": 500000,
                "frequency": "not specified",
                "currencyCode": "GBP",
                "displayPrices": [
                    {
                        "displayPrice": "\u00a3500,000",
                        "displayPriceQualifier": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            "customer": {
                "branchId": 15975,
                "brandPlusLogoURI": "/company/clogo_rmchoice_5187_0012.jpeg",
                "contactTelephone": "020 8012 6808",
                "branchDisplayName": "Foxtons, Wimbledon",
                "branchName": "Wimbledon",
                "brandTradingName": "Foxtons",
                "branchLandingPageUrl": "/estate-agents/agent/Foxtons/Wimbledon-15975.html",
                "development": false,
                "showReducedProperties": true,
                "commercial": false,
                "showOnMap": true,
                "brandPlusLogoUrl": "https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/company/clogo_rmchoice_5187_0012_max_100x50.jpeg"
            },
            "distance": 8.0669,
            "transactionType": "buy",
            "productLabel": {
                "productLabelText": ""
            },
            "commercial": false,
            "development": false,
            "residential": true,
            "students": false,
            "auction": false,
            "feesApply": false,
            "feesApplyText": null,
            "displaySize": "",
            "showOnMap": true,
            "propertyUrl": "/property-for-sale/property-78658603.html",
            "contactUrl": "/property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?propertyId=78658603",
            "channel": "BUY",
            "firstVisibleDate": "2020-04-03T11:02:42Z",
            "keywords": [
                {
                    "keyword": "stpp",
                    "matched": false
                },
                {
                    "keyword": "loft",
                    "matched": false
                }
            ],
            "keywordMatchType": "no_match",
            "saved": null,
            "hidden": null,
            "onlineViewingsAvailable": false,
            "propertyImages": {
                "images": [
                    {
                        "srcUrl": "https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:9-16:9/16k/15975/78658603/15975_1130605_IMG_02_0000_max_476x317.jpg",
                        "url": "16k/15975/78658603/15975_1130605_IMG_02_0000.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "srcUrl": "https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:9-16:9/16k/15975/78658603/15975_1130605_IMG_01_0000_max_476x317.jpg",
                        "url": "16k/15975/78658603/15975_1130605_IMG_01_0000.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "srcUrl": "https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:9-16:9/16k/15975/78658603/15975_1130605_IMG_03_0000_max_476x317.jpg",
                        "url": "16k/15975/78658603/15975_1130605_IMG_03_0000.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "srcUrl": "https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:9-16:9/16k/15975/78658603/15975_1130605_IMG_04_0000_max_476x317.jpg",
                        "url": "16k/15975/78658603/15975_1130605_IMG_04_0000.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "srcUrl": "https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:9-16:9/16k/15975/78658603/15975_1130605_IMG_05_0000_max_476x317.jpg",
                        "url": "16k/15975/78658603/15975_1130605_IMG_05_0000.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "srcUrl": "https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:9-16:9/16k/15975/78658603/15975_1130605_IMG_06_0000_max_476x317.jpg",
                        "url": "16k/15975/78658603/15975_1130605_IMG_06_0000.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "srcUrl": "https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:9-16:9/16k/15975/78658603/15975_1130605_IMG_07_0000_max_476x317.jpg",
                        "url": "16k/15975/78658603/15975_1130605_IMG_07_0000.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "srcUrl": "https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:9-16:9/16k/15975/78658603/15975_1130605_IMG_08_0000_max_476x317.jpg",
                        "url": "16k/15975/78658603/15975_1130605_IMG_08_0000.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "srcUrl": "https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:9-16:9/16k/15975/78658603/15975_1130605_IMG_09_0000_max_476x317.jpg",
                        "url": "16k/15975/78658603/15975_1130605_IMG_09_0000.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "srcUrl": "https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:9-16:9/16k/15975/78658603/15975_1130605_IMG_10_0000_max_476x317.jpg",
                        "url": "16k/15975/78658603/15975_1130605_IMG_10_0000.jpg"
                    }
                ],
                "mainImageSrc": "https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:9-16:9/16k/15975/78658603/15975_1130605_IMG_02_0000_max_476x317.jpg",
                "mainMapImageSrc": "https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:9-16:9/16k/15975/78658603/15975_1130605_IMG_02_0000_max_296x197.jpg"
            },
            "displayStatus": "",
            "formattedBranchName": " by Foxtons, Wimbledon",
            "addedOrReduced": "Added on 03/04/2020",
            "isRecent": false,
            "formattedDistance": "8.07 miles",
            "heading": "Featured Property",
            "hasBrandPlus": true,
            "propertyTypeFullDescription": "2 bedroom flat for sale"
        }
```

Comment: heyya ahmed, its me InfinityTM

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese i see that you changed the name of your account

Comment: ya thats my real name. by the way, did you try for  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61012763/fastest-proxy-iteration-in-python ?

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese not yet, this question already answered multiple time previously and the target of it is suspicious a bit

Comment: that answer doesn't work. i tried. besides i started bounty on that proxy failure question of mine

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, that is useful but need the data displayed by the chrome extension on each page. Frame source shows:  dataUrl = window.location.href.replace('/extension/', '/extension-data/');

 $.get(dataUrl, function(result) {
  $('.data').html(result);
 });

Comment: @AlistairKhandy which data? [check the first link](https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/property-91252883.html)

Comment: So in that first link the chrome extension results do not show, as you need to be logged in to the extension. If you compare the image (https://imgur.com/a/mjodyts) with the first link, you can see the chrome extension results on right hand side - that is the information needed but it loads in separate frame to rest of the page as it is a third party extension. The frame source for this is in the following - view-source:https://propertydata.co.uk/extension/1.3/51.567430/-0.240132/rightmove/69421350/475000/2 but the information needed is not in this.